# Typescript error with tRPC useQuery argument types in Jest test

Tags: typescript, react-native, ts-jest, react-native-testing-library, trpc.io

I have a monorepo which contains a React Native app. Within one of the components I have the following code:

```
const { data: user, refetch } = trpc.useQuery([
    "user.get",
    { id: state.user!.id },
])

// Later I use the user I receive from this query.
// Simplified for readability
bluetoothModule.addToDevices(user.devices)
```

The `trpc` value in the above code is setup like so, across several files in different workspaces:

```
export const appRouter = createRouter()
    .transformer(superjson)
    .merge("user.", userRouter)
    // Various other routers...

export type AppRouter = typeof appRouter
```

```
export const trpc = createReactQueryHooks<AppRouter>()
```

This works fine in the actual app. However, I've now started adding a test which uses `react-native-testing-library` to test this component.

```
describe("Sensor Status page", () => {
    it("shows sensors correctly", async () => {
        render(
            <SensorStatus
                // Some unrelated props here
            />
        )
    })
})
```

When this test runs, I get the following error:

```
Type '{ id: string; }' is not assignable to type '"status" | "user.get" | "auth.authenticate" | "event.overview" | "event.temp" | "event.pressure" | "event.movement" | "event.all" | "user.all" | "device.get"'.
      Type '{ id: string; }' is not assignable to type '"device.get"'.
```

I also get this additional error, when I try to use the `user.devices` value.

```
Property 'devices' does not exist on type 'string | AuthResponse | OverviewResults | GetAllUsersResponse[] | Device | (User & { devices: Device[]; }) | { ...; }[] | { ...; }[] | { ...; }[] | { ...; }'.
      Property 'devices' does not exist on type 'string'.
```

With some more investigation, I found that it's expecting the following type for the `useQuery` function.

```
[
    any,
    "status" | "user.get" | "auth.authenticate" | "event.overview" | "event.temp" | "event.pressure" | "event.movement" | "event.all" | "user.all" | "device.get",
    any,
    [...?]
]
```

I've tried mocking tRPC, but this doesn't seem to affect affect the TypeScript compilation.

If I add `ts-ignore` comments to the component, the test will run fine. However, I'd rather not degrade the app code for the sake of a test. Does anyone know why Typescript is expecting a different type within the test, or know if a cleaner way to fix this?